# Proper Syntax When Using dot Operator in String Interpolation in Dart

Tags: variables, printing, flutter, dart, string-interpolation

In Dart/Flutter, suppose you have an instance *a* of Class *Y*.

Class *Y* has a property, *property1*.

You want to print that property using string interpolation like so:

```
print('the thing I want to see in the console is: $a.property1');
```

But you can't even finish typing that in without getting an error.

The only way I can get it to work is by doing this:

```
var temp = a.property1;
print ('the thing I want to see in the console is: $temp');
```

I haven't found the answer online... and me thinks there must be a way to just do it directly without having to create a variable first.

Comment: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#strings

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to enclose the property in curly braces:

```
print('the thing I want to see in the console is: ${a.property}');
```

That will then print the value of a.property.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can also do this, but it doesn't seem to be documented anywhere:

print('..... $a.$property1');